# Separate by loose parts creates weird pattern

Tags: objects

I'm building a submarine for 3d printing and I have a removable top lid that I want to remove from the model to machine separately. I do a SHIFT+D on my selected area and when I move it off and do a separate loose parts to make the objects independent, I get this weird staircase pattern on the back of my boat.

What is this and how do i fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the result you're looking for?

[image: Separate]

If so, then, yes, the problem was duplicate vertices - 222 to be exact. Select the whole thing, go to *Mesh> Clean up> Merge by distance*. When I did this, I still noticed two stray edges bisecting planes near the back (second time I tried I found only one for some reason) - look for them, select them, right click and choose "dissolve edges".

After that, re-select the area you want to duplicate/separate, and it should work the way you intended.

Also, is there some special reason you're separating *By Loose Parts*, instead of by *Selection*? By selection is what I used without thinking, and I can guarantee it works (I tried both ways and they both work).

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work. I found another clue. If I go into edge select mode, and try to select a block of edges, it highlights the faces if the face is enclosed by the selected edges, except for these offenders. It captures the edges but not the faces. I'll paste a pic above.

Comment: Sounds like there might be some duplicates of something somewhere. Any chance you could post the .blend file? You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Blend file attached!

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. have a look.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!